# Vue.js transition on drag and click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, css-transitions, vue-transitions

I'm trying to build a calendar component,and when I click next or prev I want a transition, I also want to add a transition when I slide, but I can't make vue transitions work. I only have one element(current Month) and after I click to go next or prev only thing It does is change the data.
To be able to add a dynamic transform: translate, because I need to get mouse position when slide, should I create 3 elements(previous month, current month, next month)? Or can I make that work only changing data?

I tried the most simple example on vue docs and every time I click on the buttons the transition doesnt work.

```
 <transition name="home">
    <Calendar></Calendar>
  </transition>

.home-enter-active,
.home-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 4s;
}


.home-enter,
.home-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And this is my calendar component.

```
<template>
    <div id="calendar" class="calendar">
        <div>
            <div>{{ state.currentMonthName }}</div>
            <div>{{ state.currentYear }}</div>
            <div>
                <ul class="weekDays">
                    <li v-for="days in state.weekNames" :key="days">{{ days }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="days">
                <span
                    @click="
                        selectDate(state.currentYear, state.currentMonth - 1, state.getLastDayOfPreviousMonth - state.startDay + day);
                        goPrev();
                    "
                    class="lastMonth"
                    v-for="day in state.startDay"
                    :key="'empty' + day"
                    >{{ state.getLastDayOfPreviousMonth - state.startDay + day }}</span
                >
                <span :class="currenDateClass(state.currentYear, state.currentMonth, day)" @click="selectDate(state.currentYear, state.currentMonth, day)" v-for="day in state.getLastDayOfMonth" :key="day">{{ day }}</span>
                <span
                    @click="
                        goNext();
                        selectDate(state.currentYear, state.currentMonth, day);
                    "
                    class="lastMonth"
                    v-for="day in 6 - state.endDay"
                    :key="'nextMonth' + day"
                    >{{ day }}</span
                >
            </div>
        </div>

        <button @click="goPrev">Prev</button>
        <button @click="goNext">Next</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transition wraps the `Calendar` component but it never changes.  Wrap only the part of the component that changes.  From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Overview):

> Vue provides a variety of ways to apply transition effects when items are **inserted, updated, or removed** from the DOM

In their example, the transition wraps an element with `v-if`, which adds/removes items from the DOM, so the transition is applied.  Move your transition inside the component around something that changes.  For example, a transition on the month:

```html
<template>
  ...
  <transition name="home">
    <div :key="state.currentMonthName">{{ state.currentMonthName }}</div>
  </transition>
  ...
</template>
```

<sub>Note: The transition has to wrap an element.  This wouldn't work without the div or some other tag.</sub>

The `key` prop forces the div to rerender when the month changes so that the transition gets triggered.  This is as suggested in the `key` [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).  Using the `key`, you can wrap whatever you want and it will all rerender when the key changes.

Here's a demo using your transition CSS with a simpler template:

```js
Vue.component('Calendar', {
  template: `
    <div id="calendar" class="calendar">
        <div>
            <transition name="home">
                <div :key="indexMonth">{{ months[indexMonth] }}</div>
            </transition>
        </div>
 
        <button @click="goPrev">Prev</button>
        <button @click="goNext">Next</button>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      months: [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
               "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ],
      indexMonth: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    goPrev() {
        this.indexMonth = this.indexMonth === 0 ? this.months.length - 1 : this.indexMonth - 1;
    },
    goNext() {
        this.indexMonth = this.indexMonth === 11 ? 0 : this.indexMonth + 1;
    }
  }
})

/***** APP *****/
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
.home-enter-active,
.home-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.home-enter,
.home-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <Calendar></Calendar>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your solution worked.
But what about dynamic transition? so lets see that I slide with my finger on phone, and I want to hold the slider at half of position,  so will show half of current month and half of next month(if I slide to the right). To achieve that I need to get the position of finger etc etc.. but to be able to work do I need to render on DOM the next month, or vue detect that I make a transition and will show that for me, like the static transition as you showed in your example?

Comment: Transitions are for animating between start and end CSS classes when inserting/removing/updating a DOM element.  I think what you described with dragging is something a bit different; it's more like the user manually moving element positioning.  You can tell it's not a transition because you would need to "pause" the animation to do it.

Comment: exactly, so for that I need to create a next and previous month already on DOM

Comment: Yup, something like that.  You probably wouldn't use a transition at all.